# System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors on Batch

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, exception, asynchronous

i am trying  to create a batch that prevent from creating duplicate records.

This is my classes and trigger

Class **batchCheckDoublonContact** :

```
global class batchCheckDoublonContact implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
public String query;
List <Contact> triggerNew;

global batchCheckDoublonContact (List<Contact> triggerNew){
    this.query = 'SELECT LastName, FirstName, Birthdate from Contact';
    this.triggerNew = triggerNew;
    
}
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contact> scope){
    
    for (Contact contactFichier :triggerNew ){
        for (Contact contactSF : scope) {                
            if (contactFichier.LastName == contactSF.LastName && contactFichier.FirstName == contactSF.FirstName && contactFichier.Birthdate == contactSF.Birthdate){
                System.debug('**** contactFichier.LastName '+contactFichier.LastName + ' ||'+ 'contactSF.LastName'+contactSF.LastName);
                System.debug('**** contactFichier.FirstName '+contactFichier.FirstName+ ' ||'+ 'contactSF.FirstName'+contactSF.FirstName);
                System.debug('**** contactFichier.Birthdate '+contactFichier.Birthdate+ ' ||'+ 'contactSF.Birthdate'+contactSF.Birthdate);
                System.debug('*****triggerNew dans le batch '+triggerNew);
                contactSF.addError('Ce contact existe déjà ! ' + contactSF.Id);
                }
        }
    }
}
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

}
```

}

class **ContactTriggerHandler** :

```
public with sharing class ContactTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {
List<Contact> triggerNew;
List<Contact> triggerOld;
Map<id, Contact> triggerNewMap;
Map<id, Contact> triggerOldMap;

public ContactTriggerHandler (){
    this.triggerNew = (List<Contact>) trigger.new;
    this.triggerOld = (List<Contact>) trigger.old;
    if(trigger.oldMap != null) {
        this.triggerOldMap = (Map<Id, Contact>) trigger.oldMap;
    }
    if(trigger.newMap != null) {
        this.triggerNewMap = (Map<Id, Contact>) trigger.newMap;
    }
}    

public override void beforeInsert(){
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore){
        Database.executeBatch(new batchCheckDoublonContact(triggerNew));
    }
   
}
public override void beforeUpdate(){
}
}
```

the class **TriggerHandler** ::

```
    public virtual class TriggerHandler {

  // static map of handlername, times run() was invoked
  private static Map<String, LoopCount> loopCountMap;
  private static Set<String> bypassedHandlers;

  // the current context of the trigger, overridable in tests
  @TestVisible
  private TriggerContext context;

  // the current context of the trigger, overridable in tests
  @TestVisible
  private Boolean isTriggerExecuting;

  // static initialization
  static {
    loopCountMap = new Map<String, LoopCount>();
    bypassedHandlers = new Set<String>();
  }
  
  // constructor
  public TriggerHandler() {
    this.setTriggerContext();
  }

  /***************************************
   * public instance methods
   ***************************************/

  // main method that will be called during execution
  public void run() {

    if(!validateRun()) return;

    addToLoopCount();

    // dispatch to the correct handler method
    if(this.context == TriggerContext.BEFORE_INSERT) {
      this.beforeInsert();
    } else if(this.context == TriggerContext.BEFORE_UPDATE) {
      this.beforeUpdate();
    } else if(this.context == TriggerContext.BEFORE_DELETE) {
      this.beforeDelete();
    } else if(this.context == TriggerContext.AFTER_INSERT) {
      this.afterInsert();
    } else if(this.context == TriggerContext.AFTER_UPDATE) {
      this.afterUpdate();
    } else if(this.context == TriggerContext.AFTER_DELETE) {
      this.afterDelete();
    } else if(this.context == TriggerContext.AFTER_UNDELETE) {
      this.afterUndelete();
    }

  }

  public void setMaxLoopCount(Integer max) {
    String handlerName = getHandlerName();
    if(!TriggerHandler.loopCountMap.containsKey(handlerName)) {
      TriggerHandler.loopCountMap.put(handlerName, new LoopCount(max));
    } else {
      TriggerHandler.loopCountMap.get(handlerName).setMax(max);
    }
  }

  public void clearMaxLoopCount() {
    this.setMaxLoopCount(-1);
  }

  /***************************************
   * public static methods
   ***************************************/

  public static void bypass(String handlerName) {
    TriggerHandler.bypassedHandlers.add(handlerName);
  }

  public static void clearBypass(String handlerName) {
    TriggerHandler.bypassedHandlers.remove(handlerName);
  }

  public static Boolean isBypassed(String handlerName) {
    return TriggerHandler.bypassedHandlers.contains(handlerName);
  }

  public static void clearAllBypasses() {
    TriggerHandler.bypassedHandlers.clear();
  }

  /***************************************
   * private instancemethods
   ***************************************/

  @TestVisible
  private void setTriggerContext() {
    this.setTriggerContext(null, false);
  }

  @TestVisible
  private void setTriggerContext(String ctx, Boolean testMode) {
    if(!Trigger.isExecuting && !testMode) {
      this.isTriggerExecuting = false;
      return;
    } else {
      this.isTriggerExecuting = true;
    }
    
    if((Trigger.isExecuting && Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) ||
        (ctx != null && ctx == 'before insert')) {
      this.context = TriggerContext.BEFORE_INSERT;
    } else if((Trigger.isExecuting && Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate) ||
        (ctx != null && ctx == 'before update')){
      this.context = TriggerContext.BEFORE_UPDATE;
    } else if((Trigger.isExecuting && Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete) ||
        (ctx != null && ctx == 'before delete')) {
      this.context = TriggerContext.BEFORE_DELETE;
    } else if((Trigger.isExecuting && Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) ||
        (ctx != null && ctx == 'after insert')) {
      this.context = TriggerContext.AFTER_INSERT;
    } else if((Trigger.isExecuting && Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) ||
        (ctx != null && ctx == 'after update')) {
      this.context = TriggerContext.AFTER_UPDATE;
    } else if((Trigger.isExecuting && Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete) ||
        (ctx != null && ctx == 'after delete')) {
      this.context = TriggerContext.AFTER_DELETE;
    } else if((Trigger.isExecuting && Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUndelete) ||
        (ctx != null && ctx == 'after undelete')) {
      this.context = TriggerContext.AFTER_UNDELETE;
    }
  }

  // increment the loop count
  @TestVisible
  private void addToLoopCount() {
    String handlerName = getHandlerName();
    if(TriggerHandler.loopCountMap.containsKey(handlerName)) {
      Boolean exceeded = TriggerHandler.loopCountMap.get(handlerName).increment();
      if(exceeded) {
        Integer max = TriggerHandler.loopCountMap.get(handlerName).max;
        throw new TriggerHandlerException('Maximum loop count of ' + String.valueOf(max) + ' reached in ' + handlerName);
      }
    }
  }

  // make sure this trigger should continue to run
  @TestVisible
  private Boolean validateRun() {
    if(!this.isTriggerExecuting || this.context == null) {
      throw new TriggerHandlerException('Trigger handler called outside of Trigger execution');
    }
    if(TriggerHandler.bypassedHandlers.contains(getHandlerName())) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @TestVisible
  private String getHandlerName() {
    return String.valueOf(this).substring(0,String.valueOf(this).indexOf(':'));
  }

  /***************************************
   * context methods
   ***************************************/

  // context-specific methods for override
  @TestVisible
  protected virtual void beforeInsert(){}
  @TestVisible
  protected virtual void beforeUpdate(){}
  @TestVisible
  protected virtual void beforeDelete(){}
  @TestVisible
  protected virtual void afterInsert(){}
  @TestVisible
  protected virtual void afterUpdate(){}
  @TestVisible
  protected virtual void afterDelete(){}
  @TestVisible
  protected virtual void afterUndelete(){}

  /***************************************
   * inner classes
   ***************************************/

  // inner class for managing the loop count per handler
  @TestVisible
  private class LoopCount {
    private Integer max;
    private Integer count;

    public LoopCount() {
      this.max = 5;
      this.count = 0;
    }

    public LoopCount(Integer max) {
      this.max = max;
      this.count = 0;
    }

    public Boolean increment() {
      this.count++;
      return this.exceeded();
    }

    public Boolean exceeded() {
      if(this.max < 0) return false;
      if(this.count > this.max) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

    public Integer getMax() {
      return this.max;
    }

    public Integer getCount() {
      return this.count;
    }

    public void setMax(Integer max) {
      this.max = max;
    }
  }

  // possible trigger contexts
  @TestVisible
  private enum TriggerContext {
    BEFORE_INSERT, BEFORE_UPDATE, BEFORE_DELETE,
    AFTER_INSERT, AFTER_UPDATE, AFTER_DELETE,
    AFTER_UNDELETE
  }

  // exception class
  public class TriggerHandlerException extends Exception {}

}
```

and the trigger ContactTrigger :

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (
before insert,before update,
before delete,
after insert,
after update,
after delete,
after undelete) {
    new ContactTriggerHandler().run();
}
```

i have this error **SObject row does not allow errors**

i can't find a way to trigger the error message without creating the record ! can someone help me please ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using Salesforce's standard [Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_map_of_reference.htm&type=5) feature? A batch class isn't going to be able to prevent records from being inserted (nor updated, nor deleted). Even if you schedule the batch to be run from a before insert trigger, batch apex executes in a separate transaction.

Comment: the contacts are imported via csv file with a screen flow, and sometimes they import a lot of records which triggers the limit errors

Comment: Which specific governor limit(s) are you encountering? How many records do you expect to be handling? The unfiltered query on `Contact` and the nested for loop with `if(rec1.field1 == rec2.field1 && ... && rec1.fieldN == rec2.fieldN)` are both red flags and can be easily improved (which would help to avoid the cpu limit and query rows limits). Also, using Duplicate Rules is probably still better (and shouldn't be causing you to run into governor limits). At any rate, more details are required here.

Comment: Thanks Derek i missunderstood the request, i finally did it with duplicate and matchiing rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.addError` is only allowed in trigger context, not in a batch context. Your snippet is executing a batch asynchronously after the trigger on the contact fires. You can't run a batch within a trigger context and expect it to finish in the same transaction.

You shouldn't be using a batch to check for duplicate contacts. Instead use a [Duplicate Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_map_of_reference.htm&type=5).